# Stop Drupal from redirecting to "Reset Password" on user account activation

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I have a Drupal dev site where users register, then get sent an email with a link that they need to click in order to verify the account. The issue is that link directs them to a page with the title being "Reset Password" (but it doesn't actually enforce a password change). How do I change the page that the user is directed to when activating their account? It shouldn't be enforcing this.

I am also using the https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan module to improve the registration process, and perhaps this is causing the issue? I am using the "Set a password" option on the plugin to force users to create a password when creating an account, so therefore the registration process should not be enforcing the user to then reset their password.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to: admin/config/people/accounts

Edit: Welcome (no approval required) Email

Replace "[user:one-time-login-url]" with "[user:validate-url]"

https://www.drupal.org/node/1412778